# Reboot and stop image booting with C-Kermit

Tags: serial-port, embedded-linux, kermit

I'm currently using c-kermit with a serial connector to my ARM-Board. So, if I type reboot into the c-kermit connected terminal, the Board reboots. Okay, then I type Space, while it boots, to get into U-Boot. This works fine.

But I want to write a script for it. So, if I execute this script I'm already in the U-boot terminal.

My currently used .kermrc is the following:

```
set line /dev/ttyUSB3
set speed 115200
set carrier-watch off
set handshake none
set flow-control none
robust
set file type bin
set file name lit
set rec pack 1000
set send pack 1000
set window 5
connect
input "reboot"
input " "
input " "
```

output instead of input also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if the below link helps you some how.

http://blog.mezeske.com/?p=483